# How to bundle multiple installation(.exe) files?

Tags: installation, installation-package

Say, we have ABC.exe and CDE.exe

I want to bundle these 2 installation files into a single un-attended installation file [XYZ.exe].

And when I run the XYZ.exe it should install the above applications.

Any ideas how this can be achieved ?

Comment: You can use <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress"> IExpress </a> which already comes preinstalled in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need a **Bootstrapper**.

Try [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) if you need some logic in the bootstrapper, I haven't used it myself but it's often recommended on the [WiX](http://wix.sf.net) mailing list as a good free bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a [self-extracting archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive).